# Best Practice: Searching an API and Filtering Data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-filters

I'm generally curious to what the best practice is for this. I'm making a http call to an API and pulling data based on a user's search query to use for search suggestions.

Do I:

A. Pull from the web api on every user keystroke, and displaying the results until the user finds their value.

B. Pull all the data first, about 200 items, and filter the data with the user's query, then display the suggestion data to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset is small, you can download the entire list during initialization. However when the dataset is large, you should debounce the keypress event and only call the API after once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how large the database is. There is some point in which the dataset becomes too large so that data takes annoyingly long to download.

A: Better for larger databases, which cannot be dowloaded wihout suffering in performace.

B: Can be used with small databases however should not be used with large databases due to high downloading times.